# Non-minimal coupling of the gauge fields to the matter

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, spinors

Does any one know the physical meaning of the following gauge invariant gauge coupling to the spinors?  $$\bar \psi F_{\mu \nu} [\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu] \psi$$ This coupling is not minimal, as $$\bar \psi(\partial_\mu + ig A_\mu) \psi$$

Comment: That's not a renormalizable coupling, in 4d.  You'll see such terms in effective field theories, but generally only when you're fairly close to the scale where they cease to be effective..

Answer (score 1):

First, note that Your term is implicitly contained in an expression for the on-shell process $e \gamma\to e$ at tree level (with momenta $p, q \equiv p - k,k$ correspondingly), where $\gamma$ formally corresponds to external field $A_{\mu}$:
$$
\tag 1 M_{e\gamma\to e} \sim \bar{u}(p)\gamma_{\mu}u(k)A^{\mu}(q) \equiv \bar{u}(p)\left(\frac{(p+k)_{\mu}}{2m_{e}} - \frac{i\sigma_{\mu\nu}}{2m}(p-k)^{\nu}\right)u(k)A^{\mu}(q) 
$$
Here $u$ is called spinor polarization vector, and $\sigma_{\mu\nu} \equiv \frac{i}{2}[\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}]$. We see, that Your term is the second summand of $(1)$.

Second, note that loop corrections to process $e\gamma \to e$ generate form-factors $F_{1}((p-k)^2)$ and $F_{2}((p-k)^{2})$ near the first and the second summand in $(1)$. The second one comes explicitly, when we introduce effective interaction $~\sim\bar{\psi}[\gamma_{\mu},\gamma_{\nu}]\psi$ in the lagrangian, which is precisely Your term. Thus Your term brings no new fundamental effects, just corrections to known tree-level effects.

So, let's assume the physical sense of Your coupling by treating the second summand in $(1)$. Below I'll use the representation of gamma-matrices, for which
$$
\gamma_{\mu} \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma_{\mu} \\ \tilde{\sigma}_{\mu} & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad \sigma_{\mu} = (1,\sigma), \quad \tilde{\sigma}_{\mu} = (1,-\sigma) 
$$
First, it is very attractive to study non-relativistic approximation, where $s$-th polarization $u_{s}$ (with $\epsilon_{s}$ being spin up down eigenvectors) is
$$
\tag 2 u_{s}(p)\approx \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{\sigma \cdot p}\epsilon_{s} \\ \sqrt{\tilde{\sigma} \cdot p}\epsilon_{s}\end{pmatrix} \approx \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{m_{e}}\left(1-\frac{\mathbf q\cdot \mathbf \sigma}{4m_{e}}\right)\epsilon_{s} \\ \sqrt{m_{e}}\left(1+\frac{\mathbf q\cdot \mathbf \sigma}{4m_{e}}\right)\epsilon_{s} \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
\tag 3 u_{s}(k)\approx \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{\sigma \cdot k}\epsilon_{s} \\ \sqrt{\tilde{\sigma} \cdot\mathbf p}\epsilon_{s}\end{pmatrix} \approx \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{m_{e}}\left(1+\frac{\mathbf q\cdot \mathbf \sigma}{4m_{e}}\right)\epsilon_{s} \\ \sqrt{m_{e}}\left(1-\frac{\mathbf q\cdot \mathbf \sigma}{4m_{e}}\right)\epsilon_{s} \end{pmatrix}
$$
Second, it's convenient to divide $\sigma_{\mu\nu}(p-k)^{\nu}A^{\mu}$ term on two parts:
$$
\tag 4 i\sigma_{\mu\nu}q^{\nu}A^{\mu}(q) = \alpha_{i}E_{i}+\Sigma_{i}B_{i},
$$
where $\alpha_{i}=\gamma_{0}\gamma_{i}$ is called velocity, while $\Sigma_{i} \equiv \frac{1}{2}[\gamma_{i},\gamma_{j}]$ is the spin operator.

It is not hard to obtain by using $(2)-(4)$, that
$$
\bar{u}(p)i\sigma_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}(q)u(k)\simeq \text{const}_{1}(\bar{S}\cdot \mathbf B) + \text{const}_{2}([\bar{S}\times \mathbf q] \cdot \mathbf E (\mathbf q)),
$$
where 
$$
\bar{S} \equiv \epsilon^{\dagger}\frac{\sigma}{2} \epsilon  
$$
The first summand corresponds to spin magnetic moment interaction with magnetic field, while the second summand is called spin-orbit interaction.

In conclusion, Your summand generates radiative corrections to spin-orbit coupling and magnetic moment coupling.